# Word or Phrase for the artificial accumulation of deadlines or restraints through levels of management

Tags: phrase-requests

For instance, let's say state law allows minors to work until **11:00PM** on school nights. Company policy says that minors can work until **10:30PM** to be safe. The regional manager then dictates that minors can only work until **10:00PM** so they don't risk violating company policy. Your local office then makes a policy that minors can't work later than **9:45PM**. Finally, your shift supervisor hurries the minors out the door 5 minutes early, and encourages them to clock out by **9:30PM**. The restriction of the **11:00PM** clock out became **9:30PM** as it progressed through levels of management.

Is there a word or phrase to describe this artificial accumulation of restrictions?

Comment: Perhaps *CYA creep*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **regulatory thrust** or **regulatory inflation**.

You may also refer to an **excess of cumulative restrictions**.

Answer (score 1):

*Bureaucracy* has been used to describe an overly convoluted system. It is not it's exact meaning, but a vernacular connotation that has developed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureaucracy